# Cmake installation in linux

Tags: linux, cmake

First, i install cmake, it successfully installed. But in terminal cmake command not found. I searched google, and follow the instruction and move the bin of cmake from opt to system file.

And then the terminal recognise the cmake command, but still some error about share file occur, so i move the doc and share file from cmake to system file as well.

After that, no error when i type cmake in terminal. So i proceed to cmake /root/ettercap to install ettercap. But there is a couldnt find curses error occur.

HELP ME

Comment: `CMake` is usually installed via your package manager.

Comment: @drescherjm can u tell me what exactly should i do to install a workable cmake?

Comment: `So i proceed to cmake /root/ettercap to install ettercap. But there is a couldnt find curses error occur.` - You need to install `curses` (development package). CMake itself works well for you.